# How to call python function with optional parameters

Tags: python, optional-parameters

I've got the following function:

```
def create(self, name, page=5, opt1=False, opt2=False,
                        opt3=False,
                        opt4=False,
                        opt5=False,
                        opt6=False,
                        *parameters):
```

Is it possible to assign only one of the optional parameters, and some *parameters? e.g.

```
create('some name', opt4=True, 1, 2, 3) # I need 1, 2, 3 to be assigned to *parameters
```

Most of the time, I don't need to change the values of opt1...opt6, I only need to change maybe one of them, and assign some other `*parameters`. So I am looking for a way to avoid setting opt1...opt6 if I don't want to change their default value.

Comment: how will use use 1 2 and 3, how is a user to know what they do?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham They could be any arbitrary list of numbers. Not necessarily `1, 2, 3`. They could be `34, 100, 12, 18`.

Comment: what I meant was the optional *parameters is going to be treated as an iterable in your code so you could make another keyword arg `nums=None` and take an iterable as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.x, Try putting `parameters` before any of the default arguments, example -

```
def create(self, name , *parameters, page=5, opt1=False, 
                                  opt2=False,opt3=False,
                                  opt4=False,opt5=False,
                                  opt6=False):
    print(parameters)
    print(page)
    print(opt4)

In [31]: create('C', 'some name', 1, 2, 3, opt4 = True)
(1, 2, 3)
5
True
```

Please understand that with this method, you can only call the arguments with default value using named arguments.

---

For Python 2.x , you can try using `*parameters` and then `**kwargs` for the default parameters -

```
>>> def create(self, name, *parameters, **kwargs):
...     kwargs.setdefault('opt4',False)  #You will need to do for all such parameters.
...     print(parameters)
...     print(kwargs['opt4'])
... 
>>> create('C', 'some name', 1, 2, 3, opt4 = True)
(1, 2, 3)
True
```

Again, only way to set the values for `opt1...opt6` or `page` , etc would be using named arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Well for sure this is not nice, 
but you can probably work on variants of this

```
def create(name, page=5, opt1=False, opt2=False,
           opt3=False,
           opt4=False,
           opt5=False,
           opt6=False,
           *parameters):
    print(parameters)
    print(page)
    print(opt4)

myArgs = dict(zip(['page','opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4','opt5','opt6'],create.func_defaults))

myArgs['opt4']=True
create("MyName",**myArgs)
```